# How to join encrypted and plain sight columns in Spring Data JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables in a database (PostgreSQL), both of which have an `id` field that is a primary key, a common `example_id` and other fields.

```
A { id, example_id, first_name, last_name } <- Here example_id is always encrypted
B { id, example_id, qty, beds } <- Here example_id is always in plain sight
```

When I insert and read data from A, I use the `@ColumnTransformer` annotation to use the `pgcrypto` built-in function to encode and decode the `example_id` field.

```
@ColumnTransformer(
  forColumn = "example_id",
  read = "pgp_sym_decrypt(example_id, 'my_key')",
  write = "pgp_sym_encrypt(?, 'my_key')"
)
private String exampleId;
```

The problem now is this: how do I perform a JOIN between the two tables on the `example_id` field? Is there a JPA annotation to encrypt or decrypt a column on the fly before performing the match? Can it be done at the DB level? Or do I need to create a custom JPA query or move the logic to the application level?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you execute a native SQL that does such joining?